# How to raise traceback of other class in main class in python

Tags: python, pyqt4

I was coding in python and added Trace-backs for error handling.

For better understanding, lets say i have 3 classes.

C1 = Main Class

TraceBack = Other Class

My Main class will import other classes (TraceBack) and create instances of these class and proceeds as coded. For error handling i imported `traceback` module in all 3 classes and updated my code within `try: except:` Everything is working fine as desired.

Now i got an idea, to keep traceback only in main class. As other classes are imported in the main class.

my **C1.py** looks like below

```
import traceback
from TraceBack import C3

class tracebackTest():

    def __init__(self):

        try:

            self.c3_Inst = C3(1,0)
            self.c3_Inst.sub()             

        except Exception as ex:

            TraceBk = traceback.format_exc()
            print 'Error Raised from Trace Back\n%s' % TraceBk

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtGui

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = tracebackTest()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

my **TraceBack.py** looks like below

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class C3(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,x,y):

        super(C3,self).__init__()

        self.a = x
        self.b = y

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test',self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.sub)
        self.show()


    def sub(self):

        result = self.a / self.b

        print 'result %s' % result
```

In `C1.py` after creating instance i called `self.c3_Inst.sub()` immediately, which will give below trace back from the Exception.

```
Error Raised from Trace Back
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PBL_Data\Development\Showtime_Python\RnD\TraceBack_1a.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.c3_Inst.sub()
  File "D:\PBL_Data\Development\Showtime_Python\RnD\TraceBack.py", line 37, in sub
    result = self.a / self.b
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

But when i click the button in the window. I get below error, which is not raised from Exception in `C1.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PBL_Data\Development\Showtime_Python\RnD\TraceBack.py", line 37, in sub
    result = self.a / self.b
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Can any one tell me actual approach for trackback to work in the PyQt which are connected to widget signals.

Comment: What is it that you want to happen?

Comment: Traceback is not catched in c1.py when button is pressed. Its not going to Exception at all.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you click the button, Python is long past that `try..except` surrounding `self.c3_Inst = C3(1,0)`. If you want to catch the exception in `c1.py`, you'd need to put the `try..except` around `app.exec_()`.

Comment: its not working. its not going into `except` block even when i keep `try..except` around app.exec_().